# Expectation value of $Y= \lfloor(\frac{x}{2})\rfloor+1$

Tags: probability

I need help to solve this question:
Let us define $X \sim \text{Geo}(2/3)$, $Y=\Big\lfloor \frac{X}{2} \Big\rfloor + 1$.
Find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$=?

I cant seem to get the infinite sum correctly, if someone can give me any tip or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$Y=\begin{cases}k,&\text{if } X=2(k-1)\\k,& \text{if } X=2(k-1)+1\end{cases}$$ So, for any $k\in \mathbb N_{>0}$, $$P(Y=k)=P(X=2(k-1))+P(X=2(k-1)+1)$$

Comment: So do you recommend finding $P_Y(k)$ first and then calculate its expectation value? Instead of going straight to the expectation value based on the sum of all Rx?

Comment: Yeah, its a safe alternative. But going directly to $E[Y]=E[\lfloor X/2 \rfloor]+1$ should also be possible.